# Unable to click button using Selenium JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am not able to click the login button, my code is correct and there is no iframe or window:

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('SignupTest', () => {
    const driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

    it('signup with valid email and valid password', async () => {
        await driver.get('https://ca.letgo.com/en');
        const loginButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Log In')]"));
        driver.execute("arguments[0].click()",loginButton)
        //await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Log In')]")).click();
        //name=email
        //name=password
        //name=name
        //xpath=//span[contains(.,'Sign Up')]
        //await driver.sleep(20000);
    });
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: Have you tried to check if the element identified with the locator using `findElements`?

Comment: @supputuri, no it does not work

Comment: meaning either xpath is not correct or it may be in some iframe. Can you check both the conditions in the chrome dev tools.

Comment: @supputuri i do not think there is an iframe. can you check here - https://ca.letgo.com/en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element with text as **Log In** is actually within a *child* `<span>` tag (of the `<button>` tag) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  button[data-test='login'][data-testid='login']>span
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  //span[text()='Log In']
  ```

**Note**: You need to induce *WebDriverWait* while you attempt to invoke `click()` on the element with text as **Log In**.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is using javascript for running the selenium means. i suggest you 
using nightwatch js which is uses the selenium and node js.

In your case you can do the below.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
```

or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id<locator>));
```

You can also check the visibity before click using `isDisplay()` . If it prints true then perform the click action.